# How can I redirect depending of country code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ip

I have script where I get client info from server, so I get country code like "MX" and "US":

```
<script>
    $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
        $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
        $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
        $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
    }, "jsonp");
</script>
```

So I have two different webpages within different languages, I want to change webpage depending of country code I received.

For example:

If `country code = MX` redirect to `index.html`

else if `country code = US` redirect to `EngIndex.html`

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: Why not submit the country code and let the server decide what page to return?

Comment: `if (response.country == "MX") { ... } else { ... }` O.o

Comment: What are you talking exactly @Gavin